# github pages symlink does not exist in includes

Tags: html, github, github-pages

The page build failed with the following error:

A file was included in `/_layouts/default.html` that is a symlink or does not exist in your `_includes` directory. For more information, see https://help.github.com/articles/page-build-failed-file-is-a-symlink/.

I am unable to locate the symlink!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I'm running into the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The symlink is term for [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) which is basically an advanced shortcut. Symlinks are created during the build process by github. They point to files within your build. If you do not use the file to build your site you may safely delete it.

If the symlinked file is necessary to build your site, make sure the file or directory it references is in your repository.

To delete the file in git use:

```
find . -type l -exec git rm --cached {} \;
```